# Use file features on Job DSL

Tags: gradle, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I´m using Job DSL and I would like to download a file, read it, and set some env variables.

```
def static setSecrets(Job delegate, Map overrides = [:]) {
    def liveUsername
    def livePassword
    def file
    new URL('https://path/file').withInputStream { i ->
        file.withOutputStream {
            it << i
        }
    }
    file.withReader { liveUsername = it.readLines().get(0) }
    file.withReader { livePassword = it.readLines().get(1) }

    def options = [
            IDENTITY_USER: liveUsername,
            IDENTITY_PASSWORD: livePassword]

    setEnv(delegate, options, overrides)

}
```

This is the exception that I´m receiving

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method withOutputStream() on null object
```

Seems like the features of file cannot being used. But being in groovy file I was expecting can use the Job DSL templates and also, all the groovy features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File is null so is throwing NPE when you call a method on it

```
def file
...
file.withOutputStream { // BANG!
```